# What is the name of this very simple spectral subtraction technique?

Tags: audio, noise, denoising, amplitude

Let $S = X + N$ be the sum of two audio signals $X$ and $N$ which are both stationnary (let's think X is a constant volume 440 Hz sinusoid and N is constant volume noise).

If the sum S has a -20 dB volume and N has a volume of -30 dB, **what is the volume of X?**   (could be RMS or peak volume, it doesn't matter here).

The answer is

```
20*log10(10^(-20/20)-10^(-30/20)) ~ -23.3
```

**i.e. X has a peak volume of -23.3 dB.**

(of course this is not true if X and N have phase-cancellation, but except this case, it works).

[image]

**Question: what is the name of this computation? i.e. find the volume of X given the volume of N and X + N?**

---

I'm using an application of this for STFT denoising (with a noise template which is N):

- if a FFT bin has -20 dB amplitude (signal S), and the noise has amplitude -30 dB amplitude for the same bin (signal N), what would be the amplitude of the denoised signal X ? Answer: -23.3 dB, **thus this FFT bin should be lowered by 3.3 dB.**

It works quite well for my noise reduction application (again here X is nearly a constant sinusoid and N constant noise), but I haven't found a name for this simple technique. What would be the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimating the power of a sum of signals depends on coherence or incoherence assumptions. Details are given for instance on [incoherent signal summing](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-leveladding.htm) or [coherent signal summing](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-leveladding.htm). Those can provide an estimate of the noise level. They can be called power sums or voltage sums. Other details in [Voltage and power add differently](https://community.keysight.com/community/keysight-blogs/rf-test/blog/2017/04/10/voltage-and-power-add-differently-understanding-signal-power-measurement). I'll be digging for other names.

The expectation of the energy of a sum $v$ of variables $v_1$ and $v_2$ is:

$$ E((v_1+v_2)^2) = E(v_1^2)+E(v_2^2)+2E(v_1 v_2)\,.$$

Three specific cases. If $v_1=v_2$, you get $+10\log 4 = +6 $ dB. If sources are uncorrelated, $E(v_1 v_2)=0$, so you get  $+10\log 2 = +3 $ dB. If sources are oppositive, they cancel each other, and the total energy becomes $-\infty$ dB.

Then, subtracting the noise level to the observed signal is an instance of (scalar) hard thresholding, called [spectral subtraction](https://sound.eti.pg.gda.pl/denoise/noise.html) in the Fourier domain. As eluded to in your [Spectrogram with square or non-square magnitude of STFT: power vs. magnitude](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/51737/15892) question, scalar spectral subtraction on the observed STFT ${S}(\tau,\omega)$ can be performed with a power law, as:

$$|\overline{X}(\tau,\omega)|^\alpha=\max\left(|{S}(\tau,\omega)|^\alpha - \lambda|\overline{N}(\tau,\omega)|^\alpha,0\right)\,.$$

The recovery of the noiseless phase is a full different world.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a little something, are you sure about this source http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-leveladding.htm? `Adding of two incoherent (noncoherent) sound pressure levels or voltage levels: 10*log10(10^(A/10)+10^(B/10)). Adding of two values of the same level results an increase of the total level of 3 dB.` This isn't true for **voltage**, even if incoherent, right? When I add two constant-volume **incoherent** signals peaking at -30 dB in an audio software, I get -24 dB, and not -27 dB.

Comment: I cannot speak for the case you mention. I have added some computations and three cases